# toggle between 2 tmux layouts

Tags: vim, tmux

I often run Vim in a tmux session to I can run tests in an adjacent pane. On a smaller monitor, I either have to sacrifice more Vim screen real estate than I'd like, or make the test pane too small to read the full results (which is fine if everything passes, but not when there are failures and I need to see the details).

Then my workflow becomes:

- trigger tests from within Vim
- switch to test pane (`last-pane`)
- zoom pane to occupy full window (`resize-pane -Z`)
- read the results
- restore original layout (`resize-pane -Z`)
- switch back to Vim pane (`last-pane`)

I wanted to add a key binding that I could use when I'm in the Vim pane to zoom the test pane (hiding Vim), and be able to use the same binding once zoomed to restore the original layout, returning me to Vim. This is what I came up with, but I wonder if there's a better way I can do it. I had to set, check, and unset an environment variable to save the state that would support toggling back and forth with the same key binding. I also haven't figured out how to make the toggle state specific to a window (right now, any multi-window session shares the state across all its windows, so this doesn't work correctly)

```
bind Space if-shell '[ -z "${ALT_PANE_ZOOM+x}" ]' \
                    'select-pane -t :.+; resize-pane -Z; set-environment ALT_PANE_ZOOM 1' \
                    'set-environment -u ALT_PANE_ZOOM; last-pane'
```

*Update*:
I found a simpler solution. Rather than relying on a per-window environment variable, I can leverage `-F` and the `window_zoomed_flag` format variable:

```
bind Space if-shell -F '#{window_zoomed_flag}' \
                       'last-pane' \
                       'select-pane -t :.+; resize-pane -Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your tmux.conf, create a keybind which:

1. Saves the zoom state
2. Switch to the last pane, unzooming if a pane was zoomed in
3. Conditionally zooms depending on the zoomed state in #1

-

```
bind key run-shell "tmux setenv zoomed $(tmux display -p '#{window_zoomed_flag}')"\; \
         last-pane\; \
         run-shell "test $(tmux display -p '#{zoomed}') -ne 0 || tmux resize-pane -Z"
```

Note that the backslash escapes on the semicolons command separators are required.